# Can airflow work with compiled python dag?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is it possible for airflow to recognized compiled python code? I'm in beginning stage of this research. If this is not possible, I'm thinking of having non-compiled python dag execute compiled executables. Thoughts or recommendations? Thank you in advance for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiled python code (.pyc) files are not inspected by the Airflow scheduler.

You will need to have python files (.py) which contains the DAG/task instantiation for Airflow to recognize it as a pipeline.

Once you have a pipeline declared, you can leverage any operator to perform tasks.

I believe you would be using BashOperators since that will allow you to execute bash commands for executing compiled executables.

Comment: I had a feeling this wasn't possible and I may have to try the suggestion you made. Thank you Alan!